# React Native app bundle crash. Unable to load script

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I released my app BUNDLE on Google Play, and it crash at beginning. If I install manually the APK it runs correctly.

This is the error I got:

```
2020-07-31 13:13:29.944 25035-25086/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: create_react_context
    Process: com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx, PID: 25035
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running a Metro server (run 'react-native start') or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release.
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.jniLoadScriptFromAssets(Native Method)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.loadScriptFromAssets(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JSBundleLoader$1.loadScript(Unknown Source:10)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle(Unknown Source:18)
        at com.facebook.react.q.a(Unknown Source:180)
        at com.facebook.react.q.a(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.facebook.react.q$e.run(Unknown Source:68)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

- React Native version: 0.62.2
- Android gradle plugin version: 3.5.2
- Gradle version: 6.0.1

I recently changed the build version:

- buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
- minSdkVersion = 21
- compileSdkVersion = 29
- targetSdkVersion = 29